# How do I download source code from particular repo with only files that have been changed or added during a particular commit in that repo?

Tags: git, github

I am working on a project referencing a particular remote repo by another user. A recent commit history has files which I require for my project. Is there any method to just download such files which were added during this commit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add the repo to your remotes

```
git remote add anotherUser git://repo
```

Fetch updates

```
git fetch --all
```

then use

```
git cherry-pick sha-id-of-commit
```

to load commit into current branch.